# Im getting directed to Posts page (edit.php) instead of saving post in Wordpress(Can't save posts)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, windows-server-2016

I'm having an issue on my Windows server 2016 with ISS 10. 
I am running Wordpress on it but after we've updated the server I can't make changes to pages anymore.

**I can make small edits on the small pages** but when i try to edit my homepage (It has a visual editor and more content) then i get directed to edit.php and the edits I did aren't saved.

**I've tried this so far**: Increasing the value of `max_allowed_packet=32M` in my.ini file in C://Program Data/ MYSQL/ MSQL Server 5.7/ . I've updated all these:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M 
post_max_size = 64M 
memory_limit = 64M
```

The weird thing is that it all worked before we changed the server and now it doesn't work anymore.

I think the problem is something with the size of queries but I feel like im running into a wall..

Please help!

Comment: Nope - how can that be done?

Comment: The site is a Wordpress site so it uses PHP

Comment: I am editing the config files with Atom but does that have a matter?

Comment: But do you think that it is the PHP that fails and not the MYSQL db?

Comment: The MYSQL error logs or what error logs? :)

Comment: Ahh okay... Hmm - is that all server errors that are logged there?

Comment: Can't find anything in it..

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to rm my comment and leave this one so people know what's tried: **no log error**